# Can I use XQuery in Groovy scripts within SoapUI?

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy, xquery

I am trying to use XQuery within groovy scripts within SoapUI but not sure if this is possible.

I need to query XML files. For example, find the number value from a Firstname=Jim and Surname=Booth that all belongs to the Summary.

```
<Summary>
    <Number>123</Number>
    <Surname>Booth</Surname>
    <FirstName>Jim</FirstName>
</Summary>
```

I have looked into XPath and GPath but don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

> "I have looked into xPath and GPath but don't think it is possible."

I don't know about groovy and whether it support XQuery or not, but your example case can be implemented in XPath as follow :

```
//Summary[FirstName="Jim" and Surname="Booth"]/Number
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy does support XPath and XQuery.

http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML.html

http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML+with+XQuery.html